# Stop comboBox's selectedIndexChanged event from firing when the form loads

Tags: winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have a form with a `ComboBox` that provides a dropdownlist. On the comboBox's `SelectedIndexChanged event`, am running some code, but I don't want that code to run when the form loads. Unfortunately, when I load the form (before I make a selection in the combobox), `SelectedIndexChanged` of the combobox fires (I think when the combobox is `databinding`). Is there a way of avoiding such behaviour?

Comment: Not sure about on the desktop, but in .NET Compact, this event actually appears to fire before the Form_Load event, which is really problematic - nothing on the form is even set up yet when this code gets hit. On CF, the solution is unfortunately a form variable that gets set at the end of Load, and then the event handler checks for this variable before it fires.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

If you want to react only when the user change the selected item in the combo box, then it is better to subscribe to [SelectionChangeCommitted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted.aspx).

Comment: But what to do in case of autocompete?

Comment: @Arijit Mukherjee right. When typing a value into textbox instead of selecting directly. It won't trigger SelectionChangeCommitted event

Comment: Damn, I have been searching the web for quite a while to find a simple solution like this. I have been using the SelectionChanged event and it worked in VB.Net - WPF and now using it on C# - WinForms and it doesnt work or maybe it is just me. Thanks!

Comment: Akams Razor - the simplest solution is the most likely (and the best in this case).

Answer (score 14):

You can simply unbind the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, call your `fill` function and bind the `SelectedIndexChanged` event again. Unfortunately, this doesn't work with a grid.

For example:

```
this.cmb.SelectionChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.cmb_SelectionChanged);
cmb.fill(); //Your function
this.cmb.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cmb_SelectionChanged);
```

Answer (score 11):

Be sure to set the `DataSource` property in your `onload()` function after assigning the `ValueMember` and `Datamember` properties.

This will help you to solve your problem!

Comment: Please add more info that elaborates your thinking.

Comment: @Ranjith: can you elaborate?

Comment: Solves the problem. Thanks but please elaborate.

Comment: Assigning a new DataSource fires a "selectedIndexChanged" event.

Comment: lol, what is this craziness =D! Thank you though!

Comment: It´s perfect!. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Why not have a `boolean` flag that indicates when your `Form` has finished loading?

In your `SelectionChanged` event, check if the `boolean` flag is `true`. If it is `true` then handle the event, otherwise ignore it.

Comment: booooooolean.. SelectionChangeCommitted much nicer

Comment: There is already a boolean flag ` Control.Created` telling you, that the form has finished loading, which is also valid for forms.

Comment: `ToolStripComboBox` variation does not have a `SelectionChangeCommitted` event.  So, this method will have to do.  Or, to prevent race conditions, use `lock` and `Monitor.TryEnter`.

Comment: @user1734987: That's not the same thing. There could be initialization code that needs to be completed and Control.Created won't fire that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution that leaves your code almost untouched:

In the SelectedIndexChanged event, check if the myComboBox handle is created using the ([IsHandleCreated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.ishandlecreated?view=netcore-3.1)) method. Another added check is to check if the user is actually focusing your combobox control to change selected index.

```
 private void myComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (myComboBox.IsHandleCreated &&  myComboBox.Focused)
        {
           // Do something here
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to add a SelectedValue != null check as well to this, and then it's a perfect solution.

Comment: Yes, this is going to be a good added check too.

Comment: myComboBox.Focused is usually False

Answer (score 1):

VB

```
RemoveHandler lbxNomes.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf lbxNomes_SelectedIndexChanged
lbxNomes.DataSource = dst
Label1.Text = String.Format("Encontrados {0} Sócios nesta pesquisa", dst.Rows.Count)
Label1.Visible = True
AddHandler lbxNomes.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf lbxNomes_SelectedIndexChanged
```

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me in a way with the following code:

```
  private void ddlChapter_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlChapter.SelectedValue != null)
        {
           // Do something here
        }
    }
```

Comment: SelectionChangeCommitted will stop to call index change items, once all items loaded into dropbox then you can select one by one only, it will increase your loading speed also.