# How do I know if the USER changed the Selected Item in ComboBox?

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox

The issue is that the SelectedIndexChanged event is called both when the user makes the change and when the change is made by the application code setting SelectedItem.

Is there a way to tell if the item was changed by the direct actions of the user from the mouse or keyboard?

Comment: This question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263240/how-to-stop-a-comboboxs-selectedindexchanged-event-from-firing-when-the-form-lo

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this [SelectedChangeCommitted MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted.aspx)

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;

    // Change the length of the text box depending on what the user has 
    // selected and committed using the SelectionLength property.
    if (comboBox.SelectionLength > 0)
    {
        textbox1.Width = 
            comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Length *
            ((int) this.textbox1.Font.SizeInPoints);
        textbox1.Text = comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```