# Executing an action only when I select an item form the combo box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` and in the form's load event it's populated with data. Now when I select an Item form the `ComboBox`, it should perform some actions. So I know few events which can be used in this case like

```
SelectedIndexChanged

SelectedValueChanged
```

etc.

But the problem is those events are raised even when setting the `DataSource` of the ComboBox and selecting a default index etc. when the form is loaded.

```
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt;

    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

What am I trying to do is that I just want to execute an action only when **I** **select** an item form the  combo box. Is there a mouse event that could be used in this case?

Comment: Use `SelectionChangeCommitted`...only fires on user click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `comboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted` Event seems to do that.

Otherwise you could set a boolean value before you bind the datasource which you can use inside the event to ignore it.

```
private bool blnIgnoreEvent = false;

// in Form_load
blnIgnoreEvent = true;
ComboBox1.DataSource = dt;
blnIgnoreEvent = false;

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!blnIgnoreEvent)
    {
        // go ahead
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is another event that better handles what you'd like to do. XIVSolutions has a neat work-around for the event firing when you bind the data source: [How to prevent selectedindexchanged event when DataSource is bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111879/how-to-prevent-selectedindexchanged-event-when-datasource-is-bound)

Also, since `SelectedIndexChanged` works for all cases, why not just handle the first?

```
if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
  {
    return;
  }
```

If -1 corresponds to a value you'd like to be able to select, just use a private field to store some `bool` that you check to determine whether or not it is the first time the action has been executed.