# .NET c# avoid selectedIndex event when populating ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net

I have a little problem when loading a ComboBox.

The question is that in the phase of loading data, the default selectedIndex event fires.

How can I prevent this during the load process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop comboBox's selectedIndexChanged event from firing when the form loads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263240/stop-comboboxs-selectedindexchanged-event-from-firing-when-the-form-loads)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent selectedindexchanged event when DataSource is bound?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111879/how-to-prevent-selectedindexchanged-event-when-datasource-is-bound)

Comment: And many more. Just do a quick search and you'll find them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use a global variable

```
Boolean isLoaded = false;
```

in your selectedIndexChange add this code

```
if(!isLoaded)
{
isLoaded = true;
}
else
{
 /// write your code here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the event and re add it after the loading of the data is completed.

```
    combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= combo_SelectedIndexChanged;
    //Do the loading of the data into the combo
    combo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(combo_SelectedIndexChanged);
```