# WinForms SelectedIndexChangeCommitted not firing

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, event-handling

I'm populating a combobox from a datasource and I have code for when the user changes the selection in the combobox. So obviously I don't want the code in the SelectedIndexChanged method to fire on form load.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111879/how-to-prevent-selectedindexchanged-event-when-datasource-is-bound) was answered by suggesting two things:

1) Before and after loading the data to the combobox use this code:

```
private void LoadYourComboBox()
{
    this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        // Set your bindings here . . .
    this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
```

I tried that with this code:

```
this.cboSelectCategory.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(cboSelectCategory_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

However, the `cboSelectCategory_SelectedIndexChanged` part has a red error squiggly and hovering over it says: `The name cboSelectCategory_SelectedIndexChanged does not exist in the current context`. I tried that code in both the form_load and the method that actually populates the combobox.

2) That same SO question had the answer to use the event `SelectedIndexChangeCommitted`.

```
private void cboSelectCompany_SelectedIndexChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedCat = cboSelectCategory.SelectedValue.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(selectedCat);
}
```

But that event isn't firing when I change the selection in the combobox.

Am I missing something somewhere? Is my code off or in the wrong place?

Comment: Do you have a method called  `cboSelectCategory_SelectedIndexChanged` in your code?

Comment: @LarsTech - I added the event, added the code to remove/add the event in the form load event and added this in the SelectedIndexChanged event: `Console.WriteLine("This shouldn't fire on form load");` The event did fire on form load - but no errors.

Comment: Maybe if you showed us YOUR code rather than code from another SO question we could be of more help!

Comment: @Caius & LarsTech - sorry, guys - I don't know what I did wrong/different, but adding the SelectedIndexChanged event is now being prevented from firing on form load so it's working as needed. Is it Monday??

Comment: `SelectedIndexChangeCommitted` (in the title) is a curious mix of `SelectedIndexChanged` and `SelectionChangeCommitted`. The latter event is only raised when you *manually* change an Item, while is not raised when you fill the List and the Index *may* be set to `-1` (something that you always check when subscribing to the former event)

Comment: @Jimi - thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So obviously I don't want the code in the SelectedIndexChanged method to fire on form load.

If you bind your combobox in the form's constructor (after `InitializeComponent()`) then `SelectedIndexChanged` will fire before the form is visible, so you can simply return from the selectedindexchanged event if the form is invisible:

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Code");


        dt.Rows.Add("Milk", "MLK");
        dt.Rows.Add("Bread", "BRD_WHITE");
        dt.Rows.Add("Bread", "BRD_BROWN");
        dt.Rows.Add("Coffee", "COFF");

        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Code";

    }


    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Visible)
            return;

        MessageBox.Show("a");
    }
```

It's often easier to simply return from an event handler at an unwanted time than to mess around trying to remove and add event handlers

Side note: If you use a strongly typed dataset and create the bindings using the windows forms designer, the event doesn't fire, I believe because the forms designer `InitializeComponent()` calls Begin/EndInit on the components at the start and end

Comment: Interesting solution. Short, simple and easy. Implemented! Thanks!