# How do I solve an "InvalidCastException"?

Tags: c#, winforms, casting

I'm getting an "`InvalidCastException`" during run time on the following code:

My C# WinForm code contains a comboBox which is populated from a database with the following code:

```
public void PopulateCompetitionFormatDd()
{
     var _competitionFormat            = new CompetitionFormatBL();
     cbCompetitionFormat.DataSource    = _competitionFormat.GetByAllCompetitionFormats();
     cbCompetitionFormat.ValueMember   = "CompetitionFormatId";
     cbCompetitionFormat.DisplayMember = "CompetitionFormatType";
}
```

The `ValueMember` (`CompetitionFormatId`) is a list of numbers and the `DisplayMember` (`CompetitionFormatType`) is a `string` of text. When I change the item in this comboBox during run time I get the error "`InvalidCastException`".

```
private void cbCompetitionFormat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int competitionFormat = 1;
     competitionFormat = (int)cbCompetitionFormat.SelectedValue;
}
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong and how I can get around it?

Comment: Change `(int)cbCompetitionFormat.SelectedValue` to `(int)cbCompetitionFormat.SelectedIndex`?

Comment: debug it and see what the type of `cbCompetitionFormat.SelectedValue` is.

Comment: Is `CompetitionFormatId` a number or a list of numbers?

Comment: What's the datatype of `CompetitionFormatId`? `Int32`?

Comment: Changing from SelectedValue to SelectedIndexed and adding one to the value works for me, but only because my Id happens to run from 1 to 4.  Thanks mikeTheLiar though.

Comment: **D Stanley** it's a number, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @gallie in that case, I'm going to post it as an answer for that precious reps! </repwhore>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the answer to this and it's answered on this site to another similar question.  Find answer here: [Stop comboBox's selectedIndexChanged event from firing when the form loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263240/how-to-stop-a-comboboxs-selectedindexchanged-event-from-firing-when-the-form-lo)

The answer is:
If you want to react only when the user changes the selected item in the combo box, then it is better to subscribe to SelectionChangeCommitted rather than SelectedIndex(or Value)Changed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check if it is an integer.

```
int competitionFormat;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(cbCompetitionFormat.SelectedValue, out competitionFormat);

if (result) { }
```

Comment: This solution wont build giving the following errors: Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'int.TryParse(string, out int)' has some invalid arguments 
Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: Where else are you converting

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question?

Answer (score 1):

Like the exception implies, you're trying to cast a string to an int, which is invalid. Instead, you should call something like:

```
competitionFormat = int.Parse(cbCompetitionFormat.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: This solution wont build, giving the following errors: Error 1 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string' and Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
private void cbCompetitionFormat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int competitionFormat = 1;
    competitionFormat = (int)cbCompetitionFormat.SelectedValue; // <- This is an invalid cast
}
```

`SelectedValue` returns just that - the selected value, NOT the selected index. Using the  property `SelectedIndex` will return what you want (0 indexed), and (I think) you don't even need to cast it:

```
competitionFormat = cbCompetitionFormat.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
competitionFormat = Convert.ToInt32(cbCompetitionFormat.SelectedValue);
```

**Update:**

The behaviour of SelectedValue in winforms is that it returns an `System.Data.DataRowView` object representing the underlying bound data. This, obviously cannot be converted to integer. You can cast this object to the type of object that was originally bound to the combobox

```
competitionFormat = ((Competition) cbCompetitionFormat.SelectedValue).CompetitionFormatId;
```

Comment: This solution gives me the following error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: This solution is building now but giving the following runtime error.  (I like the way you're thinking though.)  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'GolfScoringSystems.RealTimeSolutions.Model.Competition'.

Comment: Try `competitionFormat = ((Competition) cbCompetitionFormat.SelectedItem).CompetitionFormatId`

Comment: Nah, still getting the same run time error.  There surely has to be a way of accessing the detail in the object?  Thanks for your help though.