# Input string was not in a correct format in combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, parsing, converters

I have a `Drop Down List` . I need the value of my `DDL` when the index changes.So i do this :

```
 private void CMBGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           int id=int.Parse(CMBGroup.SelectedValue.ToString());
           //do something with id
       }
```

In `form load` i fetch my data :

```
        goodGroups=objGoodGroupRepositoy.GetAll().ToList();
        CMBGroup.DataSource = goodGroups;
        CMBGroup.ValueMember = "Id";
        CMBGroup.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

I have such data in my database :

```
id serial    name
1   121    g1
2   123    g2
```

But i got this error before loading my form :

```
Input string was not in a correct format
```

I got this error in here in `indexchange` event of `DDL`

```
int id=int.Parse(CMBGroup.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

The model :

```
public partial class GoodGroup
    {
        public GoodGroup()
        {
            this.Goods = new HashSet<Good>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Serial { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Good> Goods { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Is it the same dropdown that gets triggered you are trying to read data from?

Comment: check SelectIndex before parsing : if (CMBGroup.SelectedIndex != -1 ){ ...

Comment: @LIUFA What do you mean ?sorry

Comment: Put a break point in this line, check what is the value of CMBGroup.SelectedValue? Also use TryParse to avoid the exception

Comment: The value is :"System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.GoodGroup_381A295E99FC14079A3A8DA041C1F8BE808D480105E0435E91A991470A90AEF7"

Comment: @NicoD i did .but same error

Comment: Seems you are using entity framework. Check the properties Id and Name on the entity. What is the type of goodGroups ?

Comment: @NicoD i added the model details to question ,   and     List<GoodGroup> goodGroups=new List<GoodGroup>();

Comment: set the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties before the DataSource

Comment: @NicoD i checked the entity my data is loaded and works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties before the DataSource.

When the DataSource is changed, or when DisplayMember or ValueMember is changed after DataSource has been set, the binding infrastructure forces the control to rebind

Another way is to unsubscribe / subscribe to the event when modifying datasource.

Comment: i used this code in another page and it worked why ?i mean i set the value and display property after datasource?

Comment: I've updated my answer. In your case hard to guess. Maybe you use a simple datasource and the toString() method is ok. Maybe you unsubscribe the SelectedIndexChanged event ?

Comment: Yes exactly iunsubscribe the SelectedIndexChanged event,by the way thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling SelectedIndexChanged event, you can just handle the [SelectionChangeCommitted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3268120/3526156) event.

When you handle this event, you don't have to unsubscribe and resubscribe the event handler because it will only fire after you have changed the value of the combo box by selecting-not after you change the datasource.